# Another recurrence through a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> $$f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}$$
>   $$x_{n+1} = f(e^{x_n}),\ x_0>0$$ Show that $x_n$ converges to $0$.

I tried to use Lagrange's theorem, but the derivative of $f$ is not bounded so I couldn't show it converges to $0$.

Comment: I get the derivative of $f$ is $-\dfrac{\ln\left(x\right)-2}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}$. The only place the derivative is unbounded is at zero. So couldn't you define $f | x>\epsilon$ yielding a bounded derivative? And then show that $f(e^x)$ goes to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that $x_{n+1} = f(e^{x_n})=g(x_n)$ where $g(x)=e^{-x/2}x$. Now note that $0<g(x)<x$ for $x>0$ which implies that for $x_0>0$ the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is positive and strictly decreasing. Therefore it has a finite limit.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I agree. But the derivative if g is still unbounded

Comment: @asd11 There is no need to consider the derivative of $g$. Anyway $g'(x)$ is bounded in $[0,+\infty)$ (note that $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @asd11 Any nore doubts?

Comment: No. I understood it perfectly! Thank you!